# Remote connections allowed, firewall off, SSMS still can't find SQL Express

Tags: sql-server-2008

My remote server running 08 R2 can connect to it's SQLExpress instance via SSMS. db Properties has 'Permit remote connections ticked'. Firewall off doesn't help. Another thread here shows 'sqlcmd -e -s ip\instance' as a suggestion - i'm not familiar with that way in - only use SSMS - but if that's _supposed to work locally, it's not in my case.

What's the next step to implementing remote access? Is the 64 bit coming into play? 64 bit version is installed but the configuration manager has a couple nodes with reference to '(32-bit)'

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is a default install of SQL Express (ie- SQL is installed as a named instance) then make sure the SQL Browser service is running.

Answer (score 0):

Have you run the SQl Server Configuration Manager to make sure that you've enabled the appropriate network protocols for the SQL instance (TCP/IP and/or Named Pipes)? If not, that's what you need to do.